# sql compare entire set of data

Tags: sql, oracle, compare

I have two sets of data and I want to compare entire data related for particular usr id. If this data are not matched completely then give me a null.

Below I should get user_id = null because not all of the data in column access are the same

```
set a
user_id     | access 
1001        | hotel
1001        | spa
1001        | gym

set b
user_id     | access 
1001        | hotel
1001        | spa
1001        | pool
```

In below case I should get user_id = 1001 because all of the data in column access are the same

```
set a
user_id     | access 
1001        | hotel
1001        | spa
1001        | gym

set b
user_id     | access 
1001        | hotel
1001        | spa
1001        | gym
```

What should the sql query look like to get this effect?
I working on Oracle database.

Comment: What have you tried? Go read up on the MINUS operator.

Comment: What does the table look like?  Nothing is SQL is called a "set".

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate tables and want users that are exactly equivalent, then `listagg()` is a simple solution:

```
select a.user_id
from (select user_id, listagg(access, ',') within group (order by access) as accesses
      from a
      group by user_id
     ) a join
     (select user_id, listagg(access, ',') within group (order by access) as accesses
      from b
      group by user_id
     ) b 
     on a.user_id = b.user_id and a.accesses = b.accesses;
```